# Replaying an Om web session(Clojurescript)?

Tags: clojurescript, om

I would like to make an Om session from Clojurescript which can reply the whole GUI on another machine. How can I pass the atom from client to server so that only the changes are sent, so that the history of changes can be replayed somewhere else?

## Update

I have put a demo up on the web. Go to:

connecttous.co

and then click "Previous sessions" at the bottom of the web page. And the code is here:

https://github.com/zubairq/coils/tree/connecttous

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to take a look to this David Nolen project:

https://github.com/swannodette/om-sync

as he comments on the readme

> Whenever application data changes om-sync will synchronize those
>   changes via EDN requests to a server.

and also in this [twitt](https://twitter.com/swannodette/status/435125165526372352)

> another thing that om-sync gives you nearly for free - web apps that
>   work offline that easily sync when network connectivity restored

Comment: Cool. I am learning Om now and when I am more familiar with the basic I will use om-sync too. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, I have made a demo at connecttous.co of playback with Clojurescript and Om